# c/c++ module for apache

Tags: c++, c, apache

I am invoking c/c++ from PHP using shell_exec(Server is httpd).

Is there any way where I can directly execute c/c++ executables from apache?

So the Apache will always execute only 1 executable each time (this file acts as a router). And then this executable will take care of the rest.

Thanks

Comment: What's a `C++ executable`, and how is it different from any other binary?

Comment: its regular binary only. Its after what is created after compilation.

Comment: execution is still same, and it doesn't matter who executes it, apache or `shell_exec`

Answer (score 3):

You can execute it via Apache's [CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/cgi.html) (or [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html)) interface.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get your question correctly, but if you just want to execute a lot of system commands from your script, then it doesn't really matter who calls them - you still end up having to spawn new processes and pay the price for that. If you don't want to run the commands asynchronously, e.g. if you always need one result to proceed to the next step, then just keep using `shell_exec`.

Unless I'm misunderstanding and you are actually *compiling* C++ code from within your PHP script. That'd be something else.